# cgo: Go struct reflection in C++?

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I need to pass unknown Go struct to C++ code and iterate over struct fields in C++. Is it possible to reflect Go struct in C++ code (called from go via cgo)?

Lets assume I have a struct

```
type Zuzu struct {
    name string
    age float32
    arr []int
}
```

I create an instance of this struct and pass it to C++ code:

```
var x = &Zuzu{}
function_cpp( x ) // call C++ code
```

The `function_cpp()` must be able to "traverse" the x and get access to each type and each member of the `Zuzu` instance pointed by `x` without the prior knowledge of the `Zuzu` type.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: cgo can't talk directly with C++, you need to call it through a C function. Unless you provide it, there is no type information passed into the C/C++ code, which may have been compiled ahead of time, and linked via a shared library.